# How can i clear a gridview row on button click C# UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm making a Blackjack game for school. For every one who doesn't know how first you get 2 cards after those 2 you need to hit for a 3 card. But if i add the third card and use the function to show the cards in your hand the first to need to be cleared from the screen so they won't be displayed twice.The name of my gridview is gvPlayer.

i'v tried this:

```
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            gvPLayer.Rows.ClearValue();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                _hand.AddCard(_deck.DrawCard());
            }
            ShowPlayer();
        }
```

But the `gvPLayer.Rows.ClearValue();` doesn't work strangely, does anyone know how i get the code working. Thanks already

Comment: You could just rebind your GridView after every hit...either with an empty collection (basically like clearing it) or with a Collection<Cards>  (sorry, had VB on my mind in my original comment)

Comment: I have a collection of cars that has been made the moment the game starts for the first 2 cards, that has been added to the gvPlayer gridview. What i want is that the collection will be cleared off the gridview, but the collection will re-show after that added with the third card.

Comment: Don't know if it makes sense

Comment: Let me get this straight, when the user "hits" for another card, you want the GridView to be completely empty for a period of time? Or do you want the GridView to be automatically updated showing 3 cards now?

Comment: I want the gridview to be updated.

Comment: Then you need  to update the DataSource and then DataBind again.

Comment: It looks like _hand is your In-Memory object of cards.....so something like ````gvPlayer.DataSource = _hand```` and then ````gvPlayer.DataBind()````

Comment: And how do i do that then, new to coding.

Comment: Obviously, at some point in your code you are binding to that gvPlayer GridView right? Probably on Page_Load after you've added the first two cards. Or else it would never display 2 cards already.

Comment: And why do you have a For Loop that only iterates 1 time? Seems odd and pointless.

Comment: yes in my ShowPlayer(); i'll add it

Comment: Do not post code that is meant to help identify the problem in a comment. Please update your original message with the code, or else people may not even see it as the comments exceed a few.  EDIT: Thanks for the update.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/1JZ2Oq7

Comment: Information for GridView class (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview?view=netframework-4.8)  -- To me, it seems your structure is off. Your front-end HTML seems like it should have a TemplateField for the image you are wanting to display. The button to hit should be outside the GridView.  If the player "hits", you then update your _hand object with a new card, rebind the grid, and databind it.  You'll then have an RowDataBound event for the GridView...inside there you find the TemplateField for the image and update it.

Comment: i can send u my project you can see it yourself then

Comment: I think you need to struggle through this rather than someone doing it for you.  Do some research on the GridView and learn by trial and error.  The good thing about test code is that it can always be rolled back and restarted. Play around.

Comment: Well, it's not that i want someone to make it for me. i just want to understand why this won't work

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/WkOOVYD

Comment: I don't know which row that you want to clear, if you want to clear all the items you could call `gvPLayer.Items.Clear()` method. and if you want to clear specified row, you need get the item index where in the row, then remove them.